# is Magento thread-safe?

Tags: php, apache, magento, thread-safety, worker

Is anyone using Magento with Apache worker MPM?

I've read conflicting reports of stability and security using worker instead of prefork, but have also read that worker is much faster than prefork.

Answer (score 10):

PHP5 is thread-safe, but PHP extensions aren't all thread-safe. So it's considered harmfull to run a PHP application on a worker-mpm. And Magento is a PHP application like any other, chances are that you are using some PHP extensions somewhere (GD, Xml, etc) and that you can't test it for thread stability (really hard to test).

But what you can do is use apache as worker (really a lot more HTTP request handled, very useful for all static files), and push PHP out of Apache (so with no mod_php).

For that you will have to use PHP with **fcgid** or **php-fpm**, that is modern version of  cgi to say it in a few words.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. So Apache is then running fast cgi, which is then running the php? How does that change the safety of the threads?

Comment: @dbcn: well with a fcgid process you won't be in threaded mode, php-fpm will create several PHP process and each process will serve several requests before dying, but only one at a time, no threads there AFAIK, so no thread-safety problems. So this is not really a response about Magento thread-safety, but validating thread-safety of magento and all code used in a custom magento is a far more complex problem :-)